tools and techniques for determining nutrient status in plants
I am interested in tools and techniques, both commercial and academic, developed for determining nutrient status and identifying limiting nutrients in growing plants. My specific interest is in alliums, but the question is general.
So far I've found two techniques. I present my understanding of them below. Please correct and supplement the presentation if needed.
Total tissue analysis for total micro and macro nutrients:
Young mature leaves are dried, ground, acid digested and fed to ICPMS or alternative method is used (nitrogen) to determine total content. Technique suffers from contamination of leaf surfaces caused by foliar fertilization and delay from onset of deficiency to actual changes in leaves. Moreover, sufficiency ranges are dependant on soil and climate.
Sap analysis:
Instead of whole leaves, only sap is tested. How sap is extracted varies across labs. For example, leaves are frozen for a short period and then pressed. The fluid extracted supposedly offers more accurate and faster results than total tissue analysis. Sap from young and old mature leaves is compared, but I assume some knowledge of sufficiency ranges  is still needed. Not sure what effects foliar fertilization has on skewing the results.
Companies that do sap analysis say sap analysis is the way to go. On the other side, total tissue analysis is preferred by other labs. An authoritative answer comparing above listed techinques is desired.
Are there any other techniques developed? For example techniques involving tissue microscopy? Thank you for your answers.
